# Typescript, экспорт модулей на клиенте

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть два файла js(ts->js). Подключены в html. В одном классы, в другом листенеры.
Во втором файле юзаются функции из первого, однако компилятор тайпа считает их неопределенными. Работает за счет того, что при компиляции он не трогает их имена и js цепляет их из глобальной области видимости. Но все-таки неприятно, хочется чтобы предупреждений подобного рода не было.
Уточню: пишу на клиенте. Не node
первый файл

```
/// <reference path="classes.d.ts" />
let digit = new Digit(number, cur_scale); // cannot find name Digit
```

classes.ts

```
class Digit {
   constructor(number, scale) {}
}
```

classes.d.ts

```
export class Digit {}
```

Comment: стоит все-таки добавить [mcve]

Comment: @Grundy, добавил. Включил свои жалкие попытки определения через .d.ts.

Comment: Мб я ошибаюсь, однако 1) в каком порядке у вас подключены файлы ? 2) производится ли превращение ts в js и как это происходит у вас?

Comment: @alexoander, Вы не поняли вопрос. Этот код работает. Задача убрать ворнинги typescript. Трансформация в джс делается пхпштормом

Comment: Какая версия Typescript?

Comment: @Grundy, 1.3 typescript

Comment: `export class Digit {}` как это так) вы должны описывать типы с помощью `declare` и `interface` к примеру. А вы что сделали? Вы просто вернули класс Digit,  а не сказали что и какой он )

Comment: Так покажите как

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интерфейс:

```
interface Digit {
    constructor(number: number, scale: number): void;
}
```

Объявление:

```
declare class Digit {
    public constructor(number: number, scale: number): void;
}
```

Можно выбрать один из. Но интерфейс это можно сказать упрощенный тип объекта, но его можно наследовать

Так же отлично описана разница между `interface` и `declare` на [англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345485/whats-the-difference-between-declare-class-and-interface-in-typescript)

UPD.
К примеру можно объявить тип класса (у меня не вызывает это фатальных ошибок, если имя интерфейса или declare такое же как у какого-то класса)

**my.d.ts**

```
declare class Digit {
  public constructor (number: number, scale: number);
  public testFunc (a: string): number;
}
```

**какойтофайл.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../typings/my.d.ts" />

class Digit implements Digit {
  constructor (number: number, scale: number) {
    console.log(`CONSTRUCTOR ${number} ${scale}`);
  }

  testFunc (a: string): number {
    return 54;
  }
}

const hello = new Digit(2, 4).testFunc("5");
```

Т.е. ты объявлением говоришь то, какие методы ты будешь использовать, поэтому сначала всегда делают описательную часть класса/объекта/функции.

Т.е. тут он будет ругаться если ты не объявишь в твоем классе метод `testFunc`, а в объявлении он будет.

Либо, если ты объявлешь что либо, ты можешь например сказать что переменная будет такого типа, то надо писать:

```
const myValue: Digit = ...
```

Comment: 1) код неверен, не отвечает на поставленный вопрос. При чем тут интерфейсы? Более того, если написать это в одном файле все подсветится фаталами.

Comment: Перечитатйте пожалуйста вопрос: как сделать класс из одного файла видимым в другом?

Comment: а по подробнее может какие фаталы? И вы должны выбрать одно из двух, а не оба сразу. вы не должны сделать его видимым, вы должны объявить его тип, и подключить в место где используете. Интерпритатор уже будет знать что этот класс, от этого интерфейса либо объявлен именно так и с такими методами и свойствами. Либо в настройках сборки указать что от чего берется (это я про типы).

Comment: @ВасилийБарабашев, фаталы, что не должны совпадать имена интерфейса и класса. Вы уточните,что и где должно находится, и к чему это было:). Свою проблему я решил, ответ написал. Если расскажете в ЛС подробнее что имели в виду буду жутко благодарен. Учусь:)

Answer (score 0):

Первый файл, worker.ts:

```
/// <reference path="classes.ts" />
let digit = new Digit(number, cur_scale);
```

Второй файл classes.ts:

```
class Digit {
   constructor(number, scale) {}
}
```

В первом файле корректно определяется класс из второго.

Comment: помоему вы путаете что то, typescript не так должен работать. Вы должны указывать ссылки на "справочные" для тайпскрипта данные, объявления типов и т.д. и и т.п. То что вы сделали это не верный подход. Опишите classes.d.ts с типом класса (может иметь любые имена) и унаследуете его, то все заработает через `class Digit implemets InterfaceForDigit`

Comment: Сейчас я разверну сервис, напишу пример)

Comment: Да, пожалуйста:)

Comment: Немного добавил, все проверил, все работало у меня локально в Webstorm

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, а если я хочу в разных классах держать деларирование класса и его вызов - как тогда? Спасибо

Comment: не совсем понял что вы имеете в виду =) в typescript я бы сказал что декларировать надо абсолютно все, иначе вся фишка языка теряется. Он же является строго типизированным языком (закос под java). В принципе это пока работает. Уточните свой вопрос. Если правильно понял что создавайте для разных типов с одинаковыми названиями разные файлы декларации, но по моему в не об этом)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев разобрался уже:) Я понимаю, что надо декларить. Потому и задал вопрос:)